# Hibernate mapping: OneToMany and OneToOne on child object property

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Here is parent class Enterprise. It has employers and one of them is president of enterprise.

```
@Entity
class Enterprise
{
   // fields

   @OneToMany
   public List<Employee> getEmployers()
   // implementation    

   @OneToOne
   public Employee getPresident()
   // implementation

}
```

Here is child Employee class. It has only info about Enterprise where he works. But question is what association should I use?

```
@Entity
class Employee 
{
   // fields

   // what association should I use?
   public Enterprise getEnterprise()
   // implementation
}
```

Comment: @Nathan - Because in an enterprise there can be many employees, not just one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you've defined the `Enterprise`->`Employers` association with `@OneToMany`, which means that an `Employer` belongs to only one `Enterprise`, you should be using `@ManyToOne`, meaning that every `Employer` belongs to max. 1 `Enterprise`, but an `Enterprise` can reference many `Employers`.

You can define the association specifics (join columns, etc) in one of the sides only, using the `mapped-by` attribute in the annotation:

```
@Entity
class Enterprise
{
   @OneToMany(mapped-by="enterprise")
   public List<Employee> getEmployers()
   // implementation    

   @OneToOne
   public Employee getPresident()
   // implementation
}

@Entity
class Employee 
{
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinTable ( name="Enterprise", joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="ENT_ID", referencedColumnName="ENT_ID") }
   public Enterprise getEnterprise()
   // implementation
}
```

In case an `Employer` could be president of a different `Enterprise` in which he is employed (seems unlikely, unless one can be president of an enterprise without being employed by it), and in case you needed to access the `Enterprise` of which the `Employer` is president from the `Employer` entity, you would need to add another association, ideally with `@OneToOne` (you would encounter problems, because @OneToOne relations require both entities to have the same @Id class). In this case I would annotate the `getPresidedEnterprise()` method on `Employer` with `@ManyToOne` for practical reasons.

Comment: but what about President field? I should use OneToOne association, but employee.enterprise annotated with ManyToOne...

Comment: @Artyom - They are not connected. There won't be a problem. The president is a different column.

Comment: It would only be a problem in case an Employer could be President of a different enterprise in which he is employed. Only then, and in case you nedd to access the Enterprise of which the Employer is president from the Employer entity, you would need to add another association, ideally with @OneToOne (you would encounter problems, because `@OneToOne` relations require both entities to have the same `@Id` class).

Comment: Is it right that in this case getEmployers is bidirectional association and getPresident is unidirectional?

Comment: Indeed, getEmployers is bidirectional because you can get Employers from Enterprise and Enterprise from Employers (normal employers). If the president of an enterprise has to be employed in the same enterprise he presides, then you could say that getPresident is bidirectional too. If not, it would be unidirectional, because you can't get the Enterprise a president presides from the Employer entity.

Comment: It's first case (president of an enterprise has to be employed in the same enterprise he presides). So looks like it should be defined as alh84001 says: add field getEnterpriseWhereImPresident annotated as OneToOne. But I may be wrong

Comment: As I said in my comments and in my edit in the answer before, you **can** use a `@OneToOne` in case the classes of the `@Id`'s of `Employer` and `Enterprise` are the same.

Comment: And, if the president is employed by the same Enterprise in which he is employed, the `@OneToOne` will be unnecessary, because it will always associate to the same entity `getEnterprise()` is already associated to.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@ManyToOne` annotation. It is the opposite side of a one-to-many relation. It says an employee can have one enterprise, but an enterprise can have many employees.

Comment: But one enterprise has many employers, it's oneToMany association. And one employee is president of enterprise - it's oneToOne association

Comment: @Artyom - Yes, use `@ManyToOne`. I didn't read your question correctly before.

Answer (score 1):

You should have two properties on the Employee class. Employee table should have a reference to an enterprise, ad enterprise should have a reference to an employee-president.

(you could also probably subclass an Employee based on the isPresident flag column, but I don't have experience with that)

```
@Entity    
class Enterprise    
{    
    // fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="enterprise")    
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){} 

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PRESIDENT_ID")
    public Employee getPresident(){}
}    

@Entity 
class Employee  
{ 
    // fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ENTERPRISE_ID")
    public Enterprise getEnterprise(){}

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="President")
    public Enterprise getMyEnterprise(){}
}
```

Comment: But what is the meaning of field getMyEnterprise for not-president employers? Will it return null value?

Comment: The `@OneToOne` mapping would not work in all circumstances, at least in Hibernate, because `Employer` and `Enterprise`'s `@Id` mappings would be expected to be of the same type.

Comment: It _should_ return null :). Or you could just make the relationship unidirectional. Also, consider what Xavi stated about id types.